# Insertar datos con Hibernate en Java

Tags: java, hibernate

Necesito insertar unas `estadísticas` que pido por teclado a un `jugador`, y la estructura de las clases son estas (Generadas por Hibernate):

**JUGADOR:**

```
public class Jugadores implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int codigo;
    private Equipos equipos;
    private String nombre;
    private String prodecendia;
    private String altura;
    private Integer peso;
    private String posicion;
    private Set<Estadisticas> estadisticases = new HashSet<Estadisticas>(0);

    public Jugadores() {
    }

    public Jugadores(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Jugadores(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public Jugadores(int codigo, Equipos equipos, String nombre, String prodecendia, String altura, Integer peso,
            String posicion, Set<Estadisticas> estadisticases) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.equipos = equipos;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.prodecendia = prodecendia;
        this.altura = altura;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.posicion = posicion;
        this.estadisticases = estadisticases;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return this.codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public Equipos getEquipos() {
        return this.equipos;
    }

    public void setEquipos(Equipos equipos) {
        this.equipos = equipos;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getProdecendia() {
        return this.prodecendia;
    }

    public void setProdecendia(String prodecendia) {
        this.prodecendia = prodecendia;
    }

    public String getAltura() {
        return this.altura;
    }

    public void setAltura(String altura) {
        this.altura = altura;
    }

    public Integer getPeso() {
        return this.peso;
    }

    public void setPeso(Integer peso) {
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    public String getPosicion() {
        return this.posicion;
    }

    public void setPosicion(String posicion) {
        this.posicion = posicion;
    }

    public Set<Estadisticas> getEstadisticases() {
        return this.estadisticases;
    }

    public void setEstadisticases(Set<Estadisticas> estadisticases) {
        this.estadisticases = estadisticases;
    }

}
```

**ESTADÍSTICAS:**

```
public class Estadisticas implements java.io.Serializable {

    private EstadisticasId id;
    private Jugadores jugadores;
    private Float puntosPorPartido;
    private Float asistenciasPorPartido;
    private Float taponesPorPartido;
    private Float rebotesPorPartido;

    public Estadisticas() {
    }

    public Estadisticas(EstadisticasId id, Jugadores jugadores) {
        this.id = id;
        this.jugadores = jugadores;
    }

    public Estadisticas(EstadisticasId id, Jugadores jugadores, Float puntosPorPartido, Float asistenciasPorPartido,
            Float taponesPorPartido, Float rebotesPorPartido) {
        this.id = id;
        this.jugadores = jugadores;
        this.puntosPorPartido = puntosPorPartido;
        this.asistenciasPorPartido = asistenciasPorPartido;
        this.taponesPorPartido = taponesPorPartido;
        this.rebotesPorPartido = rebotesPorPartido;
    }

    public EstadisticasId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(EstadisticasId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Jugadores getJugadores() {
        return this.jugadores;
    }

    public void setJugadores(Jugadores jugadores) {
        this.jugadores = jugadores;
    }

    public Float getPuntosPorPartido() {
        return this.puntosPorPartido;
    }

    public void setPuntosPorPartido(Float puntosPorPartido) {
        this.puntosPorPartido = puntosPorPartido;
    }

    public Float getAsistenciasPorPartido() {
        return this.asistenciasPorPartido;
    }

    public void setAsistenciasPorPartido(Float asistenciasPorPartido) {
        this.asistenciasPorPartido = asistenciasPorPartido;
    }

    public Float getTaponesPorPartido() {
        return this.taponesPorPartido;
    }

    public void setTaponesPorPartido(Float taponesPorPartido) {
        this.taponesPorPartido = taponesPorPartido;
    }

    public Float getRebotesPorPartido() {
        return this.rebotesPorPartido;
    }

    public void setRebotesPorPartido(Float rebotesPorPartido) {
        this.rebotesPorPartido = rebotesPorPartido;
    }
}
```

Y esta es mi clase `main` donde intento insertar los datos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //INSTANCIO VARIABLES Y OBJETOS:
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nombreJugador, temporada;
    float puntosPartido, rebotes;

    //CREO Y ABRO LA SESION, Y CREO LA QUERY PARA BUSCAR AL JUGADOR.
    Session sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    sesion.beginTransaction();
    Query<Jugadores> jugador = sesion.createQuery("from Jugadores WHERE Nombre=:nombreJugador");

    //RECOGEMOS EL NOMBRE DEL JUGADOR:
    System.out.print("Introduce el nombre del Jugador:");
    nombreJugador = sc.nextLine();

    //PASAMOS EL PARAMETRO A LA QUERY:
    jugador.setParameter("nombreJugador",nombreJugador);

    //RECOGEMOS LOS DATOS DE LAS ESTADISTICAS POR TECLADO.
    System.out.println("\nINTRODUCE LOS DATOS DE LAS ESTADISTICAS");    
    System.out.print("Introduce Temporada: ");
    temporada = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Introduce Puntos por Partido: ");
    puntosPartido = sc.nextFloat();
    System.out.print("Introduce los Rebotes: ");
    rebotes = sc.nextFloat();

    //PASAMOS EL JUGADOR OBTENIDO A UNA LISTA, Y ESA LISTA A UN ITERATOR:
    List<Jugadores> listaJugadores = jugador.list();
    Iterator<Jugadores> iterar = listaJugadores.iterator();

    while(iterar.hasNext()) {

        Jugadores jugador2 = iterar.next();

        //CREO UN ITERADOR DE LAS ESTADISTICAS DE CADA JUGADOR, YA QUE TIENE VARIAS:
        Iterator<Estadisticas> iterarEstadisticas = jugador2.getEstadisticases().iterator();

        //MIENTRAS QUE ENCUENTRE ESTADISTICAS ME LAS IRA MOSTRANDO:
        while(iterarEstadisticas.hasNext()) {

            Estadisticas estadisticas = iterarEstadisticas.next();

            estadisticas.getId().setTemporada(temporada);
            estadisticas.setRebotesPorPartido(rebotes);
            estadisticas.setPuntosPorPartido(puntosPartido);
            estadisticas.setAsistenciasPorPartido(0.0F);
            estadisticas.setTaponesPorPartido(0.0F);            
        }
    }

    sesion.getTransaction().commit();   
    System.out.println("!HECHO!");

}
```

Pero me salta este error:

> nov 14, 2019 6:40:29 PM
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl
>   mapManagedFlushFailure ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush
>   [Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value
>   mapping was incorrect) :
>   [clasesBaloncesto.Estadisticas#clasesBaloncesto.EstadisticasId@6515ecd9]]
>   Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException:
>   Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value
>   mapping was incorrect) :
>   [clasesBaloncesto.Estadisticas#clasesBaloncesto.EstadisticasId@6515ecd9]

Answer (score 0):

te falta las sentencias por fila

```
" session.save(model);"
"session.getTransaction().commit();"
"session.close();
```